# Where does Parallel Launcher store screenshots?

Tags: emulation, parallel-launcher

When I take screenshots in [Parallel Launcher](https://parallel-launcher.ca/) with the F12 hotkey, where are those screenshots saved? It's not listed in the Data Directories menu and I don't see any screenshots in the Parallel Launcher install folder.

[image: Taking screenshot with parallel launcher]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the configured screenshot folder through the Retroarch Menu. (F1 > Settings > Directory > Screenshots)

- On Windows the default is `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\parallel-launcher\data\retroarch\screenshots`.

  - For a shortcut, you can use `%LocalAppData%\parallel-launcher\data\retroarch\screenshots`
- On Steam OS the default is `/home/deck/.var/app/ca.parallel_launcher.ParallelLauncher/config/retroarch/screenshots`